# Generating consecutive invoice number in MS Access VBA, # restarting every year

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to generate unique invoice numbers for my Access (2010) database. The numbers should be in the format year+sequential number, e.g. 20101447 for the 1447th invoice of 2010. I looked around for a while, but a lot of the Google results suggest using an autonumber and I'm quite certain that's not a very solid way of doing it. (because autonumbers are only guaranteed to be unique, nothing else)

The database isn't going to be used by multiple users at once for now, but I don't feel like going with a totally hacked together solution either.

**EDIT**
I also found [this website](http://scottgem.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AB37C52C6D3752C!180.entry) that discusses sequential numbering using the DMax function. Scenario #2 is exactly what I had in mind, and I think it's good enough for my use case. I'll make sure the user is notified in the rare (for me) event that the database got changed before completely entering and saving a new invoice.

**EDIT2**
FYI: The numbering scheme isn't a fiscal requirement, but just our custom numbering. I didn't want to change without a good reason to.

Comment: How much VBA are you willing to use?

Comment: For example: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=184

Comment: That's a lot of code considering my level of understanding. Not that I don't get the code, I'm just afraid of adding too much complexity without really needing it. If it's not too hackish and wont have ugly bugs with two users, it's fine with me.

Comment: This is required by the European Union?

Comment: Are you required to store multiple pieces of data in one field? Surely there's an invoice date, and it seems to me that you can just restart the sequence for each year and leave the year out of the invoice number. If they like seeing the invoice numbers with the year before them, then you can format that for display, but there's no real need to store it that way.

Comment: @Jeff: Nope, the only requirement we have (in Germany, at least) is that the invoice numbers are unique. We just used the year+seq.number scheme in the last few years. @david: storing the values separately is just fine, but I'd to have some database level protection from duplicate numbers.

Comment: @CarstenN - I was curious. I worked on a time-billing system for an office in Germany and I recall that was a requirement because of clients in other European countries.

Comment: Since the sequence has to start ever year and you're not storing the year separately, rather than add a YEAR field that would duplicate the Year stored in the InvoiceDate field, I think your original plan was better. If the sequence didn't have to restart each year, I'd definitely eliminate storing the year in the invoice number entirely, though of course, I'd print it that way on invoices and display it that way. The users wouldn't have to know that the actual invoice wasn't stored with the year in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the ability to change the database schema:

- Add a sequential number field and a
  year field.
- To get the invoice number, combine
  these values appropriately.
- When inserting, you will have to get
  the current year and then query the
  database for the maximum sequential
  number where year = current year.
- Use these values on your insert.

If you can't change the database schema:

- Get the max invoice number where
  invoice number starts with current
  year
- Increment the invoice number.
- Use these values on your insert.

**EDIT**

If you can add another table, have a table that stores the 'max' sequential number for each year. Every insert will lock the table, get the value and then increment it.  Think of it as your invoice number generator table.

Comment: This can lead to duplicate values if there is more than one user.

Comment: Maybe this could be avoided with a two-field index set to "no duplicates" and actually verifying the data got inserted correctly whenever a new invoice is created. But that was why I was asking, my Access knowledge is still pretty shaky at best.

Comment: It would be better to store the last number in a separate table, the number can be retrieved from the table and added to the record in the before insert event. You would need to lock the table. Various aspects of this are addressed in the link I posted, although it is probably over-complicated for your present needs.

Comment: Agreed, if you can add another table, have a table that stores the 'max' sequential number for each year.  Every insert will lock the table, get the value and then increment it.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions complete with sample code

[How To Implement Multi-user Custom Counters in DAO 3.5](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;191253)  Ignore the 3.5 version number in this article.  Use whatever version of DAO is appropriate to your version of Access.

[How To Implement Multiuser Custom Counters in Jet 4.0 and ADO 2.1](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;240317)
The current version of ADO in Windows XP SP3 is 2.8 so ignore the ADO 2.1 part and use ADO 2.8.  Although 2.1 will still work.

Also what happens on January 2nd when someone enters an invoice which is supposed to be dated December 31st?  And this will happen.

Comment: Interesting but way out of my ballpark right now, I'm afraid.

Comment: What is "way out of your ballpark"? The issue of the December invoice entered in January? Or the issue of using the cited code? You will have to use code because of the requirement to restart the counter each calendar year. The only question is exactly how you implement it.

Comment: As I said earlier, I'm wary of adding complexity that I don't fully understand/need. Both links discuss properly implementing custom counters in multiuser environments. My problem was dealing with a much lower level problem.

Comment: Is it not a multi-user context? If it is, then you need to do it the way the cited articles say, or you're bound for problems.